# Question regarding Markov chains

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have this problem:

Random variables $U_1,U_2,...$ are i.i.d with the distribution, $P(0)=0.1, P(1)=0.3,P(2)=0.2,P(3)=0.4.$  Consider a new sequence $X=(X_n=X(n))$ defined as $X(0)=0, X(n)=\max(X(n-1),U_n),$ for $n\ge 1.$  I need to find the transition probability matrix for $X.$

I am completely stuck as on how to start solving this thing. Any hints are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, the entry in row "1", column "3" is the probability of going from "1" to "3" which is 0.4. We can't decrease $X_n$ so some values are 0. Each row must add up to 1.

$$        \begin{matrix}
       & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
        0 & ? & ? & ? & 0.4\\
        1 & 0 & ? & ? & 0.4\\
        2 & 0 & 0 & ? & 0.4\\
        3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.0\\
        \end{matrix}
$$